# How can I bypass the pattern lock screen of a Samsung Edge S7?

Tags: locked-out, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

**Summary**
My cousin passed away last week and my aunt is asking me to unlock his Samsung Edge S7. He had the fingerprint scanner enabled but his phone hasn't been unlocked for more than 24 hours so it requires the pattern to be entered. I've tried several of the patterns and I've also tried both Samsung find my phone and Googles device manager. Neither of them allow me to unlock the device. They only allow me to lock the device.

**Questions**

- How can I bypass the pattern code?
- How can I figure out what pattern my cousin set his phone too?
- Can I flash a custom recovery partition to have root access?
- Can I root the phone without access to the phones internals?
- Are there any other options?

Comment: Do you need access to the data in the device? or you just want to unlock the device???

Comment: @AnuragThakur Either one would work. I believe my aunt wants to see his most recent calls and texts around the time of his death.

Comment: well If it was easy to unlock a device, there is no point of adding a screen lock. According to me there is only one way to unlock the device: Factory Reset from recovery, which sadly deletes all the data from your device but unlocks it.

Comment: you could have flashed a custom Recovery but doing it requires unlocked bootloader and unlocking the bootloader formats your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. As per your question you have access to Android Device Manager which allows you to lock the device. Simply click on lock and enter the new password. It will replace the current password and you will be able to unlock the device via the password you added.As simple as that. There are more methods [Here](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/7-ways-bypass-androids-secured-lock-screen-0165540/)